# How to operate with two differents dataframes in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to make a mathematical operation by comparing the values of the two differents dataframes (A and B).

```
A = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,2,2],'s':[10,20,30,40]})
B = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2],'I':[5,10]})
```

I want add a column to A call A['ss'] in which element is equal to *s/(1+I)* where I is the value of B['I'] that have the same index of the value of the column B['a'] that is equal to the value of A['a']. I try with:

```
A['ss'] = A['s'].apply(lambda s: s/(1+ B['I'].loc[ A['a'].loc[A['s'] == s] == B['a'] ] ) )
```

but I get

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably easiest to merge the two first on `a`, this will populate the right values of `I`:

```
A2 = A.merge(B, on='a', how='left')
```

A2 now looks like this:

```
    a   s   I
0   1   10  5
1   1   20  5
2   2   30  10
3   2   40  10
```

so you can apply your operations to A2:

```
A2['ss'] = A2['s']/(1+A2['I'])
```